# $\lim \limits_{x \to e} (1-\log x)\log (x-e)$ without l'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim \limits_{x \to e}\space\space(1-\log x)\log  (x-e)$

How can is it possible to eliminate  indeterminate without using  L'Hospital's Rule ? I tried to manipulate this formula but still the same problem.

Comment: We need $x>e,$ Set $y=x/e$

$$\lim_{y\to1^+} \{1-\ln(ey)\}\ln\{e(y-1)\}=-\lim_{y\to1^+}\ln y\{1+\ln(y-1)\}$$
$$=-\lim_{y\to1^+}\ln y\ln(y-1)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let put $$x=te$$ and compute the limit

$$\lim_{t\to1^-}(1-log(te))log(e-te)$$

$$=-\lim_{t\to1^-}log(t)(1+log(1-t))$$

$$=-\lim_{t\to1^-}log(1+(t-1))(1+log(1-t))$$

$$=-\lim_{t\to1^-} \frac{log(1+(t-1))}{t-1}(t-1+(t-1)log(1-t))$$

$=-1(0-0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By mean value theorem, for $x>e$ there exists $\xi_x\in(e,x)$ such that
$$1-\log x=\log e-\log x=\frac{1}{\xi_x}(e-x).$$
Note that 
$$0<\frac{1}{\xi_x}<\frac{1}{e}.$$
Thus as $x$ gets sufficiently close to $e$ from right, it follows that
$$0\leq(1-\log x)(\log(x-e))=\frac{1}{\xi_x}[(e-x)\log(x-e)]\leq\frac{1}{e}[(e-x)\log(x-e)].$$
Then use the fact
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\log t=0$$
and squeeze law, we have
$$\lim_{x\to e^+}(1-\log x)(\log(x-e))=0.$$